# Creating Tic-Tac-Toe in C++ with classes

Tags: c++, object-oriented, console, tic-tac-toe

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int winningCombos[8][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9},{1,5,9},{3,5,7}};
int wins1;
int wins2;

class game{
private:
    int currentPlayer;
    vector <int> spaces;
    int winner;
    int numTurns;
public:
    void play();
    void update(){ system("clear"); } // Clear the screen
    void makeBoard();   // Display the current board
    void setup();   // Set up the game
    void updateSpaces(int icon, int pos);    // updates the gameboard vector
    bool checkState();  // Checks to see if the game is over
};

void game::makeBoard(){

    update();

    int pos = 0;
    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
        for (unsigned int col = 0; col < 3; col++){
            if (col != 2){
                if (spaces[pos] == 88){
                    cout << "   " << "\e[1mX\e[0m" << setw(4) << "|";
                }else if (spaces[pos] == 79){
                    cout << "   " << "\e[1mO\e[0m" << setw(4) <<"|";
                }else{
                    cout << setw(4) << spaces[pos] << setw(4) << "|";
                }
            }else{
                if (spaces[pos] == 88){
                    cout << "   " << "\e[1mX\e[0m";
                }else if (spaces[pos] == 79){
                    cout << "   " << "\e[1mO\e[0m";
                }else{
                    cout << setw(4) << spaces[pos];
                }
            }
            pos++;
        }
        cout << endl;
        if (row != 2){
            cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void game::setup(){
    // Reset the board and number of turns
    spaces.clear();
    numTurns = 0;

    // Set up a new gameboard
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        spaces.push_back(i+1);
    }

    // Decide who moves first (player1 = X, player2 = O)
    /*int num = rand() % 100 + 1;
     cout << num;
     if (num % 2 == 0){
     currentPlayer = 1;
     }else{
     currentPlayer = 2;
     }*/

    int choice;
    do {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Who is moving first?" << endl;
        cout << "1. Player 1 (X)" << endl;
        cout << "2. Player 2 (O)" << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice){
            case 1: currentPlayer = 1;
                break;
            case 2: currentPlayer = 2;
                break;
            default: cout << "Invalid Option. Please Enter Again." << endl;
        }
    }while(choice != 1 && choice != 2);
}

void game::updateSpaces(int icon, int pos){
    spaces[pos-1] = icon;
    makeBoard();
}

bool game::checkState(){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if (spaces[winningCombos[i][0]-1] == spaces[winningCombos[i][1]-1] && spaces[winningCombos[i][1]-1] == spaces[winningCombos[i][2]-1]){
            winner = currentPlayer;
            return true;
        }else if(numTurns == 9){
            winner = -1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void game::play(){

    // Setup functions and variables
    setup();
    makeBoard();
    int pos;
    bool validMove;

    do {
        validMove = false;
        do {
            cout << endl;

            // Prompt player for their move
            if (currentPlayer == 1){
                cout << "Player 1 choose a position." << endl;
            }else{
                cout << "Player 2 choose a position" << endl;
            }
            cin >> pos;

            // Check if the move is valid
            if (spaces[pos-1] == 88 || spaces[pos-1] == 79){
                cout << "This position is already filled!" << endl;
            }else if(pos <= 9 && pos >= 1){
                validMove = true;
            }else{
                cout << "That is not a valid position! Valid positions are 1-9." << endl;
            }
        } while(!validMove);

        // Update the game board according to the current player
        if (currentPlayer == 1){
            updateSpaces(88,pos);
            currentPlayer = 2;
        }else{
            updateSpaces(79,pos);
            currentPlayer = 1;
        }
        numTurns++;
    } while(!checkState());


    // Print the winner of the game
    if (winner == 2){
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!" << endl;
        wins1++;
    }else if (winner == 1){
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!" << endl;
        wins2++;
    }else{
        cout << "The game ended in a draw..." << endl;
    }

    // Update Scores
    cout << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Player 1 Wins | Player 2 Wins" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "       " << wins1 << "      |        " << wins2 << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;

}

int main(){
    // Main Menu Variables
    bool quit = false;
    int choice;
    game currentGame;

    do {
        // Main Menu
        cout << "1. Play Game" << endl;
        cout << "2. Quit" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice){
            case 1: currentGame.play();
                break;
            case 2: quit = true;
                wins1 = 0;
                wins2 = 0;
                break;
            default: cout << "Invalid choice. Please choose from the list below." << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;

    } while (!quit);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you are looking for from this code review? Right now you just have a code dump. See how to ask a good question at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. You also might want to take a tour at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour. You can get your first badge that way.

Comment: @pacmaninbw What's not clear about "Tic-Tac-Toe in C++ with classes"? I think that suffices to explain what the goal of the code is.

Comment: @200_success Well, besides a plain code dump the OP should give us a short explanation about  the overall structuring of their code and what their design deciscions were.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can shorten this a little bit

> ```
>         if (col != 2){
>             if (spaces[pos] == 88){
>                 cout << "   " << "\e[1mX\e[0m" << setw(4) << "|";
>             }else if (spaces[pos] == 79){
>                 cout << "   " << "\e[1mO\e[0m" << setw(4) <<"|";
>             }else{
>                 cout << setw(4) << spaces[pos] << setw(4) << "|";
>             }
>         }else{
>             if (spaces[pos] == 88){
>                 cout << "   " << "\e[1mX\e[0m";
>             }else if (spaces[pos] == 79){
>                 cout << "   " << "\e[1mO\e[0m";
>             }else{
>                 cout << setw(4) << spaces[pos];
>             }
>         }
> ```

you should take out the Guts, the inner if then else statement, it looks the same in both places, except for one thing.  so what I did was factor out the part that was the same

```
if (spaces[pos] == 88){
    cout << "   " << "\e[1mX\e[0m";
}else if (spaces[pos] == 79){
    cout << "   " << "\e[1mO\e[0m";
}else{
    cout << setw(4) << spaces[pos];
}
```

and then I took the one thing that makes it different and did that next.

```
if (col != 2) {
    cout << setw(4) << "|";
}
```

This way you are repeating yourself as little as possible, we have shortened the amount of lines that were written to attain this goal.

This also keeps the indentation level to a minimum.

Keep it DRY.

Answer (score 1):

## Design

The presentation of the game, the logic of which moves are possible and determining a winner, and the representation of the board are all mixed together.  This makes it hard to (for example) change the terminal interface to a Web front-end, to make a distributed two-player game, or even simply to unit-test the logic.

Changing this design will pretty much require starting from scratch, but this program is small enough that you should be able to implement it several times as you learn, and to discover what the different architectures make easy or difficult.

## Magic numbers

The `spaces` array seems to contain `88` and `79` with no explanation of where those values come from.  It's my guess that you're using an ASCII system, where those numbers are equal to `'X'` and `'O'` respectively.  If so, then it's clearer and more portable to write the character constants instead.

## Terminal codes

To clear the screen, we have `system("clear")`, but elsewhere there are embedded terminal escape codes such as `"\e[1mX\e[0m"`.  I'd say that both of these show portability problems: the first because it will only work on systems with a `clear` program in the path, and the second because (even ignoring the non-standard `\e` character) it is specific to a family of terminals (there are terminals that use different escape sequences to that).

My recommendation is to use a library such as termcap or curses to deal with these terminal-dependent sequences, to get the benefit of many years experience of terminal handling without having to re-invent it all yourself.

## Avoid `using namespace`

Keep away from `using namespace std` in particular - [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721).

## Address compiler warnings

When I compile with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Weffc++`, I get some errors that are well worth fixing:

```
162410.cpp: In constructor ‘game::game()’:
162410.cpp:15:7: warning: ‘game::currentPlayer’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
 class game{
       ^~~~
162410.cpp:15:7: warning: ‘game::spaces’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
162410.cpp:15:7: warning: ‘game::winner’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
162410.cpp:15:7: warning: ‘game::numTurns’ should be initialized in the member initialization list [-Weffc++]
162410.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
162410.cpp:186:10: note: synthesized method ‘game::game()’ first required here 
     game currentGame;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

You can fix these either by writing a constructor:

```
game::game()
    : currentPlayer{0},
      spaces{},
      winner{0},
      numTurns{0}
{
}
```

or (in modern C++) by writing default initializers at the member declarations:

```
private:
    int currentPlayer = 0;
    vector <int> spaces{};
    int winner = 0;
    int numTurns = 0;
```